# How to expose directories of an npm package to other packages in a monorepo

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna

I have a Lerna monorepo that consists of two packages: `myapp-web` and `myapp-core`. Each of those packages have top-level `src/` dirs to hold their code.

I want to be able to import `myapp-core/src/some-subdir` as `myapp-core/some-subdir` (similar to how you'd do an import to `lodash/effects` or `lodash/fp`) inside of `myapp-web` (that is, I want to avoid including the `src/` part).

I know you can set the entry point in the `main` prop of `package.json`. Can I do something analogous but manifesting the directories I want to make available from outside the package? Do I need to make named exports from the `main` file and require picks those up as `myapp-core/some-export`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to move the files from `src/` to the root of you project. However you can set this up to happen on publish. That way you keep your source files in `src/` and exclude them from your published package. That's what `lodash` and others do.

This is not unique to monorepos.